# How do I create a react / react-dom webpack alias in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, material-ui

I have created an alias for react and react-dom in my next.config.js. This is my next.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = (phase) => {
  return {
    // typescript: {
    //   ignoreBuildErrors: false,
    // },
    webpack5: true,
    webpack(config, options) {
      // const { isServer } = options;

      // if (!isServer) {
      //   config.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
      // }

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: "@svgr/webpack",
      });

      config.resolve.alias["react"] = path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "shared-js/node_modules/react"
      );

      config.resolve.alias["react-dom"] = path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "shared-js/node_modules/react-dom"
      );

      console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, "shared-js/node_modules/react-dom"));

      return config;
    },
  };
};
```

Why am I doing this?

I have a component library, which is based on material ui. This is imported to my nextjs app via a submodule (shared-js). This is the package.json for my component library:

```
{
  "name": "my-component-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.modern.js",
  "umd": "dist/index.min.js",
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rollup -c -w",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production rollup -c",
    "build-dev": "NODE_ENV=develop rollup -c --minifyInternalExports=false",
    "prettier": "prettier --write ./src"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.1",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.4.2",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.7.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.3.4",
    "react-resizable": "^3.0.4",
    "recharts": "^2.1.9",
    "rollup-plugin-import-css": "^3.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "use-react-screenshot": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.2",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "rollup": "^2.72.1",
    "rollup-plugin-delete": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-filesize": "^9.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^5.6.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Here is my package.json for my nextjs app:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^12.1.5",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0"
  }
}
```

And my folder structure for the project:

```
-.next
-node_modules
-pages
-shared-js
--node_modules
--package.json
package.json
next.config.js
```

The problem is, that I have two conflicting versions of react and react-dom (I guess) in my shared-js/node_modules and the other ones in the node_modules folder of my nextjs app. This caused the error "Invalid hook call" whenever I tried to import a component to my nextjs app. I looked into the documentation and saw that this might be because of two conflicting react / react-dom versions, which is indeed the case. So I tried to avoid this by defining this alias in my next.config.js.

Which led me here. Whenever I run `npm run dev` or `npm run build` for my nextjs app, I get this error, telling me that react-dom is apparently missing:

```
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
wait  - compiling...
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:513:35
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client'
```

Why is that? The path is correct, the dependency is there but still I get this error. Is there anything I am missing? Or something I am doing wrong?

What I already tried: Deleting node_mdoules and package-lock.json from both nextjs and my component library and reinstall them. Deleting .next and restart via `npm run dev`

Comment: Can you also share the `shared-js/package.json` file?

Answer (score 3):

that's how I solved the problem with the conflicting versions.
Good description of the problem: https://blog.maximeheckel.com/posts/duplicate-dependencies-npm-link/

My `next.config.js`

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.resolve.alias["react"] = path.resolve("./node_modules/react");
    return config;
  },
};
```